# How to split a string based on parenthesis and avoiding whitespace

Tags: java

I'm trying to reformat a string using the str.split() on string such as

"(ABD) (DEFG) (HIJKLMN)" (has one or more spaces between)

I've tried using this RegEx (Java)

```
[the example string] .split("\\(|\\)")
```

My output keeps including the "" or " " in my array from splitting, which I don't want I would want my array to be such that

array[0] = "ABC"
array[1] = "DEFG"
etc.

Comment: Just add a character class "/[()]/g"

Comment: If there's a space inside the `()`, then this would help: `yourstring.trim().replaceFirst("\\(", "").replaceFirst(".$", "").split("\\)\\s+\\(")`

Answer (score 4):

I would perform two steps, use `String.replaceAll(String, String)` to remove the `()` characters. Then, split on white-space. Like,

```
String str = "(ABD) (DEFG) (HIJKLMN)";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.replaceAll("[()]", "").split("\\W+")));
```

which outputs (as requested)

```
[ABD, DEFG, HIJKLMN]
```

Alternatively, you could use an `ArrayList` and compile a reusable `Pattern` to perform a grouping operation on the contents of `()` literals. Like,

```
String str = "(ABD) (DEFG) (HIJKLMN)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\w+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(matches);
```

which will continue to work in the face of input without white-space between `()`(s) like `String str = "(ABD)(DEFG)(HIJKLMN)";`